# Targeting inner html inside Vue.js templates

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm new with Vue.js. I want to target a value inside of html element - for example `div`. That particular element has a values from array of objects and the line is in the shape of `<div>{{array.value}}</div>`. I also applied a `v-for` directive, so it looks like this:

```
<ul v-for="(arr, index) in array"
v-bind:key="index">
<div id="el">{{arr.value}}</div>
</ul>
```

So, I want to target that `{{arr.value}}` in the same way I would use `document.getElementById("el").value` and use that different values (given with `v-for`) to compare with other equal values (in similar way like it's done in search engines).
How to do that in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `refs` instead of id attribute and bind it to the current index then read the text of that ref :

```
<ul v-for="(arr, index) in array" v-bind:key="index">
    <div :ref="'el'+index">{{arr.value}}</div>
</ul>
```

these will create refs like `el1, el2 ...`

somewhere in your script you could do :

```
 this.$refs.el1[0].innerHTML
```

or

```
 this.$refs.el2[0].innerHTML
```

to get the content of that div element

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

let app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
      array: [{
          value: 'bar'
        },
        {
          value: 'foor'
        }, {
          value: 'foobar'
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    log() {
    window.ref2=this.$refs.el2
      console.log(this.$refs.el2[0].innerHTML)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul v-for="(arr, index) in array" v-bind:key="index">
    <div :ref="'el'+index">{{arr.value}}</div>
  </ul>

  <button @click="log">log</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Just to add to the answer. The Vue documentation states:
> When used on elements/components with v-for, the registered reference will be an Array containing DOM nodes or component instances.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that, but this is done when you place `ref` in the `ul` tag next to the v-for directive

Comment: I got "TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined".

Comment: but how do you use it ?

Comment: @DennisUtzinger has a point here.  If you used keys in a v-for you will expect refs in an array, so if you access the elements by trying: this.$refs.el1[0].text.

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim, I used it inside of method which is called with @click="logger". That "logger" method looks like this : logger() { console.log(this.$refs.el2.text) ,  and it's in another component. So, it is npot in the same .vue file like that <div :ref="'el'+index"> element. Maybe, it is the problem with using of different components?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim  it helped me with finding final solution. Thanks dude.